# FinderSync appex not installed

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, finder, findersync

I have an application that implements a FinderSync app extension. The problem is that on a customer computer, it seems that FinderSync is installed only **after** Finder is restarted, but not before. The customer has osx El Capitan(10.11.2).

I have a screenshot from that customer with the application running, but finder extension not installed in System Preferences->Extensions
I also have a log file where I logged the output of the following command:

```
pluginkit -m -A -i com.xxx.xxx.xxx -v
```

which returns

```
(no matches)
```

The thing is that this happens only on that machine, all other machines we are testing on are working fine: the extension is loaded immediately after the application is opened.

Do you know why Finder does not load the appex immediately after application is running?
Is there a way to avoid this behavior?

Thanks!

Comment: have you found why this was happening, please ?

Answer (score 2):

You got to look in the System.log file for `plugin com.xxx.xxx.xxx invalidated`.

If you see that, it means that the system has kicked out your plugin. You can just re-add then.

I'm currently looking into why mine get's invalidated.

Comment: have you find why ?

Comment: @Liviu, no I didn't and to be honest, I don't work there anymore :)